# Qt: How to release memory occupied by QPainterPath when drawing is finished?

Tags: qt, drawing, qpainter

The thing is: I want to draw many many lines calculated by input data (data size above 50MB) generated from USB device. If I use QPainterPath::lineTo and QPainterPath::moveTo function to draw lines, it seems that the performance is bad and the memory will not be released.

My environment is: Windows 7 with 8G RAM and Qt 4.7.2.

For example, if the data size is 50MB, the occupied memory will be 200MB. When the previous drawing is finished and application is ready to draw next time, the 200MB will not be released. So if I draw many times, the application will crash.
The exception point in void QRasterPaintEngine::strokePolygonCosmetic(const QPointF *points, int pointCount, PolygonDrawMode mode):

```
// Draw all the line segments.
for (int i=1; i<pointCount; ++i) {

    QPointF lp1 = points[i-1] * s->matrix + offs;  //  error here, the point is NULL
    QPointF lp2 = points[i] * s->matrix + offs;    //  error here, the point is NULL

    const QRectF brect(lp1, lp2);
    ProcessSpans penBlend = d->getPenFunc(brect, &s->penData);
    if (qpen_style(s->lastPen) == Qt::SolidLine) {
        drawLine_midpoint_i(qFloor(lp1.x()), qFloor(lp1.y()),
                            qFloor(lp2.x()), qFloor(lp2.y()),
                            penBlend, &s->penData,
                            i == pointCount - 1 ? mode_for_last : LineDrawIncludeLastPixel,
                            devRect);
    } else {
        drawLine_midpoint_dashed_i(qFloor(lp1.x()), qFloor(lp1.y()),
                                   qFloor(lp2.x()), qFloor(lp2.y()),
                                   &s->lastPen,
                                   penBlend, &s->penData,
                                   i == pointCount - 1 ? mode_for_last : LineDrawIncludeLastPixel,
                                   devRect, &dashOffset);
    }
}
```

By the way, before drawing, I do the delete operation for QPainterPath but it seems not working here. Does anyone have any ideas about it? Thanks.

The following is my drawing code:

```
    int scaleFactor;
    double old_x, current_x;
    int current_y, oldval, newval, x_change_visible, tmp_x, tmp_y;
    int low = m_ui->renderAreaWidget->height() - 2, high = 20;
    int ch = getChannelNumber();
    uint64_t ss, se;

    if (sample_buffer == NULL)
        return;

    scaleFactor = getScaleFactor();

    if (painterPath != NULL)
        delete painterPath;
    if (dottedPath != NULL)
        delete dottedPath;
    if (textPath != NULL)
        delete textPath;

    dottedPath = new QPainterPath();
    painterPath = new QPainterPath();
    textPath = new QPainterPath();

    old_x = (getScrollBarValue() % stepSize);
    current_x = (getScrollBarValue() % stepSize);

    ss = (getScrollBarValue() + current_x) * scaleFactor / stepSize;
    se = ss + (getScaleFactor() * width()) * stepSize;
    if (se > getNumSamples()) // Do this _after_ calculating 'step'!
        se = getNumSamples();

    oldval = getbit(sample_buffer, ss, ch);
    current_y = (oldval) ? high : low;
    painterPath->moveTo(current_x, current_y);
    // add dummy line to indicate something
    if (ss < 100 && (isSetTriggerCondition || pretriggerPercent < 100)) {
        QPen pen;
        pen.setStyle(Qt::DotLine);
        bool textDrawed = false;

        bool isTextDrawed = false;
        for (int i = ss; i < 100; i += scaleFactor) {
            if (i >= 50 && i <= 60 && !isTextDrawed && pretriggerPercent != 100) {
                QFont font;
                //font.setFamily("Times");
                //font.setItalic(true);
                font.setPixelSize(18);
                textPath->addText(current_x, low + 1, font, QString("Pre-trigger %1%").arg(pretriggerPercent));

                isTextDrawed = true;
            }

            for (int j = 0; (j < scaleFactor) && (i + j < 100); j++) {
                dottedPath->lineTo(current_x, low);
                current_x += (double)stepSize / (double)scaleFactor;
            }
        }
        zeroX = current_x;
    }

    //current_x = (-getScrollBarValue() % stepSize);
    bool isTriggered = false;
    int oldy = current_y;
    painterPath->moveTo(current_x - ((double)stepSize / (double)scaleFactor), low);
    painterPath->lineTo(current_x, low);
    painterPath->lineTo(current_x, current_y);
    for (uint64_t i = ss; i < se; i += scaleFactor) {
        //Process the samples shown in this step.
        for (uint64_t j = 0; (j < scaleFactor) && (i + j < se); j++) {
           newval = (i + j < numSamples ? getbit(sample_buffer, i + j, ch): newval); // sample buffer is the data buffer, size is about 50M. getbit function is about to determine the specific byte in target channel is high or low.
            x_change_visible = current_x > old_x;
            if (oldval != newval && x_change_visible) {
                painterPath->lineTo(current_x, current_y);
                current_y = (newval) ? high : low;
                if (current_y != oldy && !isTriggered) {
                    isTriggered = true;
                    emit(triggerValue(getChannelNumber(), i));
                }
                painterPath->lineTo(current_x, current_y);
                old_x = current_x;
                oldval = newval;
            }
            current_x += (double)stepSize / (double)scaleFactor;
            oldy = current_y;
        }
    }
    current_x += stepSize;
    painterPath->lineTo(current_x, current_y);
```

The each data sample is one byte and I draw each one as high voltage or low voltage depends on it's value.

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: @Arnold Spence: I use the windonw task manager to monitor the memory resource.

Comment: @Stephen Chu: I posted my drawing code.

Comment: Delete the painter paths after usage, or even better, create them on the stack instead of using pointers and new.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Thanks for replay but this operation seems no luck. :(

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: I mean the memory can be released but the lines are not showing. I'm still trying something to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and shared it with you. As the sample codes I posted above, I delete the QPainterPath in paintEvent function before drawing, but it doesn't work. So I move the delete action prior to jumping to the paintEvent function, and this can release the memory occupied by QPainterPath. Thanks for all of your suggestions. :)